# Preventing navigation back in Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, caliburn.micro

I have a Caliburn Micro ViewModel inherited from Screen. The OnDeactivate should be "equivalent" to OnNavigateFrom in the View.

I want to prevent navigating back using the back button in some situation. Basically what I want to do is something like set Cancel=true in OnBackKeyPress but I want to do it in the View Model.

The OnDeactivate has a boolean close parameters, but when I set it to false there is no change.

Comment: When you navigate back from a view, you pass in your OnDeactivate?

Comment: yes, OnDeactivate in the ViewModel is called when navigating back

Comment: You want to just get the backbuttonpress event and do e.cancel = true like in the overide methode onNavigateFrom?

Comment: yes, I want to do something that is equivalent to setting e.Cancel=true in OnNavigateFrom

Comment: You don't have access to canceleventargs in your viewmodel?

Comment: no, I can attach a message to OnBackKeyPress but I do not get the arguments, maybe some Caliburn bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this :

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Interactivity:EventTrigger
        EventName="BackKeyPress">
        <Command:EventToCommand
            Command="{Binding BackKeyPressCommand}" />
    </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In caliburn micro i think it's :

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event BackKeyPress]
```

But i don't know the code syntaxe sorry.
For take canceleventargs, don't forget to write `PassEventArgsToCommand="True"`

Comment: thanks, it is `micro:Message.Attach="[Event BackKeyPress] = [Action OnGoBack($eventArgs)]"`